# Jquery multiple Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create an array in JQuery from multiple ajax requests. This is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var feedResult = [];
var feedCount = [];

var displayResources = $("#display-resources");  


var arayUrlFederalRegister = [
{ source: "FederalRegister:Beef", url : "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/documents.json?fields%5B%5D=abstract&fields%5B%5D=html_url&fields%5B%5D=publication_date&fields%5B%5D=title&per_page=2&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=beef&callback=foo"},
{ source: "FederalRegister:Safety", url : "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/documents.json?fields%5B%5D=abstract&fields%5B%5D=html_url&fields%5B%5D=publication_date&fields%5B%5D=title&per_page=2&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=safety&callback=foo"},
{ source: "FederalRegister:Listeria", url : "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/documents.json?fields%5B%5D=abstract&fields%5B%5D=html_url&fields%5B%5D=publication_date&fields%5B%5D=title&per_page=2&order=newest&conditions%5Bterm%5D=listeria&callback=foo"} ] ;

function getFederal( $thisSource, $thisURL) {
$.ajax({      
  async: true,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
 url: $thisURL,
  success: function(result) {
    var thisCount = 0;
    for (var i in result.results) {
      thisCount++;
      feedResult.push({URL:result.results[i].html_url, title:result.results[i].title, date:result.results[i].publication_date, summary:result.results[i].abstract });
    }
    feedCount.push({source:$thisSource, count:thisCount});  
  }
}); 
};

function pushAllFeeds() {
   $.each( arayUrlFederalRegister, function( index, value ) {
       getFederal(value.source, value.url );
   });
};

function displayFeeds($feedResult) {
 var output = '<div class="bsr-results well">';
 $.each( $feedResult, function( index, value ) {
      output +=
        '<h3><a href="' +
        value.URL +
        '" target="_blank">' +
        value.title +
        '</a></h3><div><div class="bsr-date">' +
        value.date +
        '</div><p>' +
        value.abstract +
        '</p></div><hr>';
    });
    output += "</div>";
    displayResources.html(output);      
};


$.when(pushAllFeeds()).then(function() {
 console.log(feedResult);
 displayFeeds(feedResult);
});

});
```

The console is displaying the **feedResult** array built up correctly (6 objects) but the **displayFeeds** function is not populating the #display-resources div element with anything so is acting on the initial empty array. Any ideas on how to deliver the argument to displayFeeds() function after all the ajax requests are done and the feedResult array is complete? Thanks.

Comment: you can't just call $.when on any function, it has to be called on a promise. pushAllFeeds doesn't return a promise, therefore it won't wait on it before calling the .then callback.

Comment: Thank you, I am documenting on .promise right now.

Comment: If I am not calling $.when on pushAllFeeds() at the end then console.log(feedResults) is also empty so I am thinking that's not entirely faulty.